# When to use AlertDialog.Builder.setTitle() vs Dialog.setTitle()?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there a reason to prefer one of these over the other?

You can call setup methods on the `Builder()` like this:

```
// #1
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("The Title");
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

or you can call setup methods on the `Dialog()` itself, such as:

```
// #2
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog dialog = buider.create();
dialog.setTitle("The Title");
dialog.show();
```

There are other methods besides `setTitle()` in question - I picked that as an example.

I suppose if I was going to be creating a bunch of identical Dialogs, then #1 would be the way to go, but for the majority of the cases where one is creating a single Dialog, this seems like a toss-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During this many years work on android i never think about that...but i am just sharing my experience...there may be other people who will give better answer instead of me...

**AlertDialog.Builder** does the settings of the attributes such as ***setTitle()*** or ***setMessage()*** and are not displayed to the user.

**AlertDialog** is the one that displays those attributes which have been set in the **AlertDialog.Builder**.

The purpose of having both as mentioned somewhere is that it allows settings to be made separately from the actual displaying which in turn makes thing convenient.

So conclusion, that factory methods are just more convenient.

Comment: Thanks Lokesh. I don't see a good distinction here though. I can also use `AlertDialog.setTitle()` and `AlertDialog.setMessage()` without displaying to the user, then save the actual displaying until later with `AlertDialog.show()`